# Static IP hosts on WiFi router with DHCP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dhcp

I have two wired hosts (a desktop and a laptop) connected to a router that also has a DHCP server enabled for WiFi access. When I restart my wired machines, they get assigned a secondary IP address by the DHCP server on the router. I want the wired hosts only to use static IP addresses. Is there any way I can have mixed static/dynamic addresses on the same router?

Both my wired machines are running Arch Linx. The router is a stock TP-Link WR1041N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than setting static IP addresses on the wired machines, you should use MAC address reservations on the TP-Link router.

This will have the same effect - static IP addresses - but without the added secondary IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with Arch Linux yet, but from what I understand, you would like to configure static addresses for both of your wired hosts.

You can take a look at the [network configuration guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration#Configure_the_IP_address) for arch linux.

Like most linux systems, you can set the IP address for an interface with the command line :

- ip addr add 192.168.1.2/24 broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev eth0

Other than that, there seems to be the dhcpcd (not to be confused with the dhcpd service) service that runs on the arch linux operating system which takes care of getting an IP address from the dhcp server. Shutting down the service would solve the issue you are having.

Comment: I've set the static IP address using `netctl`. I've also disabled dhcpcd, so I'm not sure how the secondary IP address is getting set.